# fadeToggle animation not acting as expected while fading in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using fadeToggle in my meteor project to fade some buttons in and out on click. It seems to be working fine while fading out, but while fading in the animation "flickers" and it looks like the animation is done twice. I have already tried to clear the animationqueue so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

[gif of what goes wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJVcH.gif)

here's the jquery I'm using:

```
$("#editBtn").click(function () {       
    $('.deletebtn').fadeToggle(400, false);
    $('.addbtn').fadeToggle(400, false);
    if ($("#editBtn").text() == "Edit") {
        $("#editBtn").text("Finish");
    } else {
        $("#editBtn").text("Edit");
    }
});
```

the html from the button to trigger the action:

```
<li><a id="editBtn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn resizebtn amber darken-2" href="#">Edit</a></li>
```

the html from the buttons to fade in/out:

```
<a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light amber darken-2 deletebtn right"><i class="material-icons deleteico">close</i></a>
<a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light amber darken-2 addbtn"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
```

I'm using chrome btw.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the initial CSS for .deletebtn and addbtn? I would imagine your problem lies there.

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eeqnbrsr/) of your project. The fade-ins seem to be working smoothly. I'd check the Event Listeners in the Chrome Inspector on the `<a>Edit</a>` in your original code and make sure that you only have one Click listener. As long as your `.click()` is only being applied once, the fade in should be smooth.

Comment: As a roundabout remedy, you can also put a `e.preventDefault(); setTimeout(function() {$('btn').fadeToggle(400, false);}, 0);` in your `.click()` to ensure that the fade in happens independently.

Comment: @ChrisThorsvik the problem seems to arise because of the fact that I'm using materializecss for my design indeed without the materialize classes it's working fine

Comment: I suspect the problem is caused by `waves-effect`. I suggested adding `materializecss` in tags to seek more accurate help.